# How to extract the Cookie header from a GET request in java?

Tags: java, cookies, http-headers, httpurlconnection, request-headers

I tried searching all over the web but did not find anything useful. I built a java program that sends a post request with specific parameters to a website, and the user writes his/her personal_number and authenticate using a third party app. I'm using `HttpURLConnection` so I think it handles the redirecting. The problem is, I need to extract the cookie header from the GET request after the authentication before sending any other requests. How to do it in Java?

Example from my code:

```
 public class JavaPostRequest {
    private static HttpURLConnection con;
    String url = "https://somewebsite.com/home/authentication";    

    public JavaPostRequest(long personal_number){
        try {
            URL myurl = new URL(url);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection(); //Opens a http thread


            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    
            con.setRequestProperty("Sec-Ch-Ua", "\"(Not(A:Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"98\"");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            con.setRequestProperty("Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile", "?0");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)");
            con.setRequestProperty("Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform", "\"Windows\"");
            con.setRequestProperty("Origin", "https://somewebsite.com");
            con.setRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin");
            con.setRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors");
            con.setRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "empty");
            con.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://somewebsite.com/home");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            
            String jsonInputString = "{\"personal_number\":\""+ personal_number + "\"}";

            try(OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()){
                byte[] input = jsonInputString.getBytes("utf-8");
                os.write(input, 0, input.length);
            }

            try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String responseLine = null;
                    while((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                        response.append(responseLine.trim());
                    }
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                    
                }
    
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        finally{
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }

    
    
    

}
```

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks it did work, but I think I have a problem with the Redirect.

Comment: You'll need to ask another question about that.